# Can you optimize Armature performance in Blender?

Tags: modifiers, armature, bones, performance, optimization

My scene contains one character model from Street Fighter V, and I get around 5fps. It's strange, since I can easily run that actual game at 60fps, but I suppose there are reasons Blender would be more demanding.

I noticed that removing the Armature modifier results in perfect performance, easily above 24fps. Yet, some googling led me to a post on the Blender forums claiming Armatures have minimal impact on scene performance.

This makes me think Armatures shouldn't be so demanding, and that my particular Armature is causing issues. Are there 'best practices' regarding Armature optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the game, all Armature movements (poses) have been *baked* - live previewing an Armature, editing an armature, posing, all that stuff, are not baked, and so they require a huge amount of calculations to the mesh for each bone. It's not about Blender specifically, it's just that the animations are pre-baked and require no calculations in-game. This is standard practice, there's no 3D software/computer that can do live armature calculations at 60fps.

(With a simple armature and a really nice computer, you might be able to, but that's an exception, not a rule)

Comment: I should add, with the new GPU Subdivision, you should get a *lot* better performance